# redirect output of tar uncompression to other folder

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to extract my `tar` file in remote server and uncompress the files in my home folder:

```
ssh xyz.abc.hi "tar cf ~/Documents/myabc.tar.bz2 > /home/xyz/test.suffix"
```

But it's not happening. Can anybody suggest anything? I am looking for something like mentioned in https://superuser.com/questions/345376/how-to-tar-untar-the-output-on-the-fly

Comment: `ssh user@server "tar jxvf ~/Documents/myabc.tar.bz2 -C ${HOME}"`

Comment: what should be in ${HOME}?

Comment: `$HOME` contains the path to your home directory by default.

Comment: It shows me this error `tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

Comment: Anything else? tar should give you a reason *why* it failed, too.

Comment: Your tar file ~/Documents/myabc.tar.bz2 is already created and you want to ssh it to xyz.abc.hi server. Please explain question in more detail.

Comment: I want to use ssh so that uncompression happens on that server, but files are extracted to the local file system of the calling host.

Comment: ~/Documents/myabc.tar.bz2 is on server and /home/xyz/test.suffix is on local system am I right?

Answer (score -1):

For your case, where you already have a .tar.bz2 file on the remote server and apparently want it untarred underneath a /home/xyz/test.suffix/ local directory:

```
ssh xyz.abc.hi "cat ~/Documents/myabc.tar.bz2" | ( cd /home/xyz/test.suffix/ && tar xjf - ; )
```

The `j` option is for bzip2 (de)compression.
Be careful that the file name as to come just after the `f` option

Or in a more general case: taring on the remote, untaring on the local, without creating a tar file:

```
ssh user@remote "cd /source/dir && tar czf -" | (cd /local/path/ && tar xzf - ; )
```

That exemple uses `z` for "gzip", which is a bit larger than bzip2, but *much* faster

Comment: bash: ~/myxyz.tar.bz2: No such file or directory

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors